# show custom page during building process in vue js

Tags: vue.js, webpack

i want to show a custom html page while building my vue js project (`npm run build`)
as you know while building process dist folder not exists and after build process we have dist folder .
how can i show a custom page until `build` is completely done?
i found this answer in a forum but how can i use that?
i dont think this is proper way!

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    if ( response.status === 503 ) {
        return to maintenance page
    }
    return response;
});
```

Comment: where you host your vuejs application. if you don't have dist folder which mean your provider don't have any code to execute too the axios also wont work at all. you should set the redirect at cloud level not code level.

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you explain what do you want to achieve. It seems you are using VUE version that is lower than VUE CLI 3. If you want a custom page (error page, static page, 404 page, redirection page and etc.) you can still use vue router. Adding a page after a build is not a good idea since there is no route for that when you already build your project. Install vue router, create a router file or if you already have router add this.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'


Vue.use(Router)

import PageNotFound from '@/views/pages/NotFoundPage'
import 404Page from '@/views/pages/404Page.vue'
import StaticPage from '@/views/pages/StaticPage'

const router = new Router({
  routes: [
        {
      path: '/static',
      name: 'Static Page',
      component: StaticPage
    },
    {
      path: '/404',
      name: '404 Page',
      component: 404Page
    },
    {
      path: '*',
      name: 'PageNotFound',
      component: PageNotFound
    }
  ]
})

export default router
```

You just need to redirect the user using these from your view files

```
this.$router.push('/static')
this.$router.push('/404')
```

if there are no matching route the user will automatically redirected to **Page Not Found** page

Comment: when you execute (npm run build) until the process is completely done you cant see the website on browser (during process) and you will see blank page . i want to show somthing instead of blank page

Comment: ah you mean something like maintenance mode during the npm run build?

Comment: I suggest you use a continuous integration/ continuous delivery (CI/CD) so there will be no interruption to your production or try just to upload the dist folder to your production and don't upload the source files because that is intended for development/staging purposes. Try to create 2 servers, one for production and one for development/staging